# Compute $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{|x|^a}{(1+x^2)^b}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, gaussian-integral

Let $a,b$ be real numbers, we consider the integral in form $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{|x|^a}{(1+x^2)^b}dx$. I know that when $a=0$, then the integral finite iff $b>1/2$.

I want to find a necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b$ for which $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{|x|^a}{(1+x^2)^b}dx$ is finite, but I have no idea. Could any one help me?

Comment: Why did you add the complex analysis tag? Did you come across this integral in the application portion of a complex analysis class?

Comment: I come across this when I want to check if $z^a(z+i)^b$ belongs to Hardy space or not. When $a=0$ this is known that, we can use complex integral to compute.

Comment: What contour did the $a=0$ case use to compute the result

Comment: Hint: $$|x|>1\implies\frac1{(x^2+x^2)^b}<\frac1{(1+x^2)^b}<\frac1{(0+x^2)^b}\\|x|<1\implies\frac1{(1+1)^b}<\frac1{(1+x^2)^b}<\frac1{(1+0)^b}$$

Answer (score 0):

As $|x| \to \infty$, the integrand is asymptotic to $|x|^{a-2b}$, so what you  need for convergence there is $a-2b < -1$.

As $|x| \to 0$, the integrand is asymptotic to $|x|^a$, so here you need $a > -1$.

BTW, the integral can be evaluated in closed form (under the above assumptions): the answer is
$$ {\frac {\Gamma \left( -1/2+b-a/2 \right) \Gamma \left( a/2+1/2
 \right) }{\Gamma \left( b \right) }}
$$

Comment: Just a note: this is called the Beta function, and there's a lot of literature about it (just read its Wikipedia page)